# Generating API signature (hmac sha256) but getting wrong signature error

Tags: python, hash

This is the link to the API reference manual : https://data.azbit.com/swagger/index.html

For each request you will need API-Signature:

1. Calculate `signatureText = publicKey + requestUrl + requestBodyString` (no separator symbols in-between)

   publicKey - example: `b2H9TlfRu6MOgG4m9wvrf9maSUiPsQJEui0JrB`

   requestUrl - full url of request, example:
   `https://data.azbit.com/api/orders`

   requestBodyString - JSON request body as a 1-line string, example: `{"isBid":true,"currencyPairCode":"ETH_BTC","amount":0.01,"price":0.02}`

   Then signatureText = `b2H9TlfRu6MOgG4m9wvrf9maSUiPsQJEui0JrBhttps://data.azbit.com/api/orders{"isBid":true,"currencyPairCode":"ETH_BTC","amount":0.01,"price":0.02}`
2. Convert signatureText as UTF8-string to bytes
3. Compute HMACSHA256 hash from signatureText-bytes
4. Convert hash-bytes to HEX-string

```
import requests
import json
import hmac
import hashlib

pkey = "publickey"

skey = "secretkey"
 
url = "https://data.azbit.com/api/orders"
 
data = {"side":"sell","currencyPairCode":"BTC_USDT","amount":0.01,"price":29700}

sigtext = pkey+url+str(data)

sighmac = hmac.new(skey.encode('utf-8'), sigtext.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

rheaders = {"API-PublicKey":"publickey", "API-Signature":str(sighmac)}

response = requests.post(url, headers=rheaders, json=data)
 
print("Status Code", response.status_code)
print("JSON Response ", response.json())
```

I'm getting wrong API signature error.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try `sigtext = pkey+url+json.dumps(data)`

Comment: I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be how the `sigtext` is constructed:

`sigtext = pkey+url+str(data)` is not the same as `sigtext = pkey+url+json.dumps(data)` (for example single vs double quotes around strings).

The correct code:

```py
import requests
import json
import hmac
import hashlib

pkey = "publickey"

skey = "secretkey"
 
url = "https://data.azbit.com/api/orders"
 
data = {"side":"sell","currencyPairCode":"BTC_USDT","amount":0.01,"price":29700}

sigtext = pkey+url+json.dumps(data)  # <-- json.dumps() here!

sighmac = hmac.new(skey.encode('utf-8'), sigtext.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

rheaders = {"API-PublicKey":"publickey", "API-Signature":str(sighmac)}

response = requests.post(url, headers=rheaders, json=data)
 
print("Status Code", response.status_code)
print("JSON Response ", response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

`str(data)` does not generate JSON but a human readable representation of the `data` dict. While this representation may look similar to JSON, it is a different format and is not compatible with JSON.

As such, to correctly generate a JSON representation of your data, you have to specifically generate JSON here as indicated in the documentation you have quoted in your question. This can look like this:

```
sigtext = pkey+url+json.dumps(data)
```

The rest of your code should then work mostly unchanged. One potential gotcha however may be the exact amount of whitespace created by `requests` for the JSON representation in the request body as you have to make sure that the JSON representation of your data is exactly the same in the request body and in the signature text. If requests uses a maximally compact representation, you may have to use `json.dump(data, separators=(',', ':')`, i.e:

```
sigtext = pkey+url+json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Alternatively, you can also generate the single JSON representation once and use it in your `sigtext` calculation and pass it to requests too, e.g.

```
json_data = json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':'))
sigtext = pkey+url+json_data

# ...

rheaders = {"API-PublicKey":"publickey", "API-Signature":str(sighmac), "Content-Type": "application/json"}

response = requests.post(url, headers=rheaders, data=json_data)

# ...
```